# Command requires line break to finish

Tags: go, process, command

I'm trying to run *sqlite3* as a process with Go. I would like to combine `cmd.Stdin` with `bytes.Buffer` and `os.Stdin`. Nevertheless, when I write the `.quit` command on the stdin bytes buffer, the program does not exit directly but is waiting for a line break from `os.stdin`. When it receives the line break from `os.stdin`, it thus exits.

I tried to invoke `os.Stdin.Write([]byte("\n"))` but it didn't work. How can I exit directly after the `.quit` command without any interaction with `os.Stdin`?

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/sqlite3")

    bufOut, bufErr, bufIn := &bytes.Buffer{}, &bytes.Buffer{}, &bytes.Buffer{}

    cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(bufOut, os.Stdout)
    cmd.Stderr = io.MultiWriter(bufErr, os.Stderr)
    cmd.Stdin = io.MultiReader(bufIn, os.Stdin)

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Execute .help command on sqlite3
    if _, err := bufIn.Write([]byte(".help\n")); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Execute .quit command on sqlite3 (should exit here)
    if _, err := bufIn.Write([]byte(".quit\n")); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Nevertheless, it requires a '\n' from os.Stdin before exiting

    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("out:", bufOut.String(), "err:", bufErr.String())
}
```

Comment: There's a data race on `bufIn`.  Fix by writing the commands to `bufIn` before calling `cmd.Start()`.  What's the purpose of reading form `os.Stdin` given that the program attempts to quit before `os.Stdin` is read?

Comment: @CeriseLimón It is just an example showing the issue. It should be possible to read from `os.stdin` or from `bufIn` before the `.quit` command. By the way, I tested to write to `bufIn` before calling cmd.Start() however I still have the issue

Comment: The posted code reads from os.Stdin after issuing the `.quit` command. Use the following to execute the `.quit` command after executing `bufIn` and/or `os.Stdin`: `cmd.Stdin = io.MultiReader(bufIn, os.Stdin, srings.NewReader(".quit\n"))`. Because the command exits on EOF, there's no need to finish up with the `.quit` command. In any case, you should fix the data race.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is with your use of MultiReader here:

```golang
cmd.Stdin = io.MultiReader(bufIn, os.Stdin)
```

From the [docs for MultiReader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiReader) (emphasis added):

> MultiReader returns a Reader that's the logical concatenation of the provided input readers. *They're read sequentially.*

The other relevant info comes from [the documentation for `Cmd.Stdin`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd). It says that if `Stdin` is not `nil` or an `*os.File`, then

> during the execution of the command a separate goroutine reads from Stdin and delivers that data to the command over a pipe. In this case, Wait does not complete until the goroutine stops copying, either because it has reached the end of Stdin (EOF or a read error) or because writing to the pipe returned an error.

So what's happening in your program is this: `cmd`'s `Stdin`-reading goroutine goes to read from the MultiReader `bufIn`. First it reads the data you've written to `bufIn`, but then it tries to read more. The MultiReader sees that `bufIn` is exhausted and moves to `Read` its next argument, `os.Stdin`. When you call `cmd.Wait`, it blocks waiting for the MultiReader to send EOF, but the MultiReader itself is blocking trying to read from `os.Stdin`. Nothing happens until you send EOF (eg. hit ctrl-D) or hit enter. (I'm not quite sure why hitting enter works, since that wouldn't normally entail an EOF, but I'll update if I figure out the details.)

The other problem is the race condition, as [Cerise Limón notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58804673/command-requires-line-break-to-finish#comment103896601_58804673) - it's entirely possible for the goroutine to read from your `bufIn` before you've written to it, in which case anything you subsequently write to `bufIn` will be ignored.

Rather than using buffers to communicate with your process, you'll be better off using `cmd.StdoutPipe` and `cmd.StdinPipe`. This doesn't solve the whole problem, though - you can't use blocking IO to communicate with a subprocess in an interactive way, because you'll end up waiting to read from a process that is waiting for you to write a command. Probably your best bet will be to use a goroutine to read from the command and use select with timeouts to read output until it's reasonably certain there's no more coming.

Here's one implementation. It needs some fleshing out, error handling at the very least, but it works. `startScanner` sets up the goroutine to read lines from the command's output and write them to a channel. `readLinesFromChannelWithTimeout` reads from the given channel until the given timeout passes with no data. Note that you *must* call `cmdIn.Close()` before calling `cmd.Wait()` or the latter will hang indefinitely.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func readLinesFromChannelWithTimeout(ch chan string, timeout time.Duration) []string {
    var lines []string
    for {
        select {
        case line, ok := <-ch:
            if !ok {
                return lines
            } else {
                lines = append(lines, line)
            }
        case <-time.After(timeout):
            return lines
        }
    }
}

func startScanner(cmdOut io.ReadCloser) chan string {
    ch := make(chan string)
    go func(ch chan string) {
        defer close(ch)
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(cmdOut)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            ch <- scanner.Text()
        }
    }(ch)
    return ch
}

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/sqlite3")
    cmdIn, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
    cmdOut, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    cmd.Start()

    ch := startScanner(cmdOut)

    var lines []string

    io.WriteString(cmdIn, ".help\n")
    lines = readLinesFromChannelWithTimeout(ch, time.Millisecond*100)
    fmt.Printf("Got %d lines from .help\n", len(lines))

    io.WriteString(cmdIn, ".show\n")
    lines = readLinesFromChannelWithTimeout(ch, time.Millisecond*100)
    fmt.Printf("Got %d lines from .show\n", len(lines))

    cmdIn.Close() // vital! Wait() will hang otherwise
    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```